# J2ObjC - Android Libraries

Tags: java, android, objective-c, j2objc

I'm trying to convert my Android project to an Objective C project with J2ObjC. So far, I managed to convert all my files which are not using any libraries. However, every class which uses a library receives an error. For example: `error: package android.location does not exist`.

In the documentation it states that you can't convert UI elements in J2ObjC. But the `android.location` package does not contain UI elements (for as far as I know). Is there a way to convert these classes anyway? Or is it only possible to convert code which is not using libraries?

Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

j2objc supports the [Java runtime API (JRE)](https://developers.google.com/j2objc/javadoc/jre/reference/), and only a very small subset of the [Android API](https://developers.google.com/j2objc/javadoc/android/reference/).

There is no plan for j2objc to ever support the [android.location API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html), since its package description states that its use is no longer recommended. For a cross-platform app, I suggest defining a minimum interface to meet your app's specific location needs, then implement that interface for each platform using the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) libraries.